# how to send data using ajax and jquery to cross browser?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post

I am using this code to send data to cross browser

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com/requestFileTransfer/",
    data: JSON.stringify(requestPostData),
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',                
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',         
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

However it is giving me an error:

> NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed
>   http://example.com/requestFileTransfer/?callback=jQuery11110937573491767841_1461846171546&%22ZXlKamIyNTBZV04wU1VRaU9pSXhNVGN4SWl3aVptbHNaVTVoYldVaU9pSmlZVzV1WlhJZ0tERXBMbXB3WnlJc0ltWnBiR1ZUYVhwbElqbzBNemt5TVRrc0ltWnBiR1ZVYVdOclpYUkpSQ0k2TVRVMk9UUTBORFV6TXpneU1Td2lkRzlyWlc0aU9pSXdaVGRqTkdFeU1DMDBNVEZoTFRReFpEY3RPV1kyTUMwME1XVTRPV1UxTWpNeE5HUWlMQ0prYVdkbGMzUWlPaUpSWEdiQ2ljSzB3cmxNd3EzQ3JjS2dROEttdzdWY0lqWlpmOEtGd3JzeVF5Sjk=%22&_=1461846171547"

How can I solve this? The cross browser server accepts JSON requests. How can I send a AJAX request to receive JSON using jQuery?

if i send the request like this it will give me success.

```
var textPostdata = BASE.utils.base64encode(BASE.utils.base64encode(JSON.stringify(sendData)));
//  console.log(textPostdata);
    BASE.request({
                url : "http://example.com/sendTextMessage/",
                method :"POST",
                headers : {

                    "content-type": "application/json",
                },
                    body : textPostdata
                },
            function (err,result,body) {
                    //console.log(typeof body);
                    var textbody = JSON.parse(body);
                  // res.send('controller success');
        // res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.send("controller success");
        //res.end();
 });
```

But if i am trying using $.ajax then it will give me error "405 method not allowed"

Comment: The 405 method not allowed error means the endpoint you're calling doesn't support POST requests. You need to use the HTTP verb it is expecting, eg `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` etc

Comment: but when i calling through json request its working but this time i need to send through jquery

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'json request'. There's no such thing.

Comment: var textPostdata = BASE.utils.base64encode(BASE.utils.base64encode(JSON.stringify(sendData)));
// console.log(textPostdata);
 App.request({
    url : "http://example.com/sendTextMessage/",
    method :"POST",
    headers : {

     "content-type": "application/json",
    },
     body : textPostdata
    },
   function (err,result,body) {
     //console.log(typeof body);
     var textbody = JSON.parse(body);
            // res.send('controller success');
  // res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.send("controller success");
  //res.end();
 });

Comment: check this if i am doing this then it will acceptable no error appears

Comment: but if i am using  $.ajax({
     url: "http://example.com/requestFileTransfer/",
     data: JSON.stringify(requestPostData),
    type: 'POST',
     crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
     
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        
         
 
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    if ( console && console.log ) {
      console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
    }
  });
  } its give me network error any suggestion please

Comment: This is all detail you should put in the question, in the comments here it's unreadable. Please use the edit button above.

Comment: please check again the question i edited

Comment: you know why this happening?